# How do I make it so it doesn't erase the stored number in my variable?

Tags: python, while-loop, addition

```py
if Cards[CardExtra] == Cards[10] or Cards[CardExtra] == Cards[11] or Cards[CardExtra] == Cards[12]:
    NumbrMore = 10
    **total = (int(Numbr) + int(Numbragain) + int(NumbrMore))**
    print(total)
```

What I want it to do is if you draw, it adds the number to your total, and you can draw again and it would add that number to your total, but it currently erases "NumbrMore"
This is all in a while loop also

Comment: Could you add your entire code please? or more code that is relevant

Comment: You need to remember to append to total instead of overwriting it - `total +=`

Comment: Read [ask] and [mre] - [edit] your question into answerable shape.

Comment: `if Cards[CardExtra] == Cards[10] or Cards[CardExtra] == Cards[11] or Cards[CardExtra] == Cards[12]:`  can most probably be shortened to `if Cards[CardExtra] in (Cards[10], Cards[11], Cards[12]):`

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it might work

```
if Cards[CardExtra] == Cards[10] or Cards[CardExtra] == Cards[11] or Cards[CardExtra] == Cards[12]:
    NumbrMore = 10
    total += (int(Numbr) + int(Numbragain) + int(NumbrMore))
    print(total)
```

Comment: I got it, thanks for the help!